# Changing default routing in Ionic which is having tab module

Tags: ionic-framework

This is the route in my ionic app which is

1. src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Code is this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  }

//Some other codes
]
```

I want to load login while the app loads also i want to load tabs while http://localhost:8100/tabs/tab1

So far i am not able to do this most of the answers are not seems like working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread from ionic forum has helped the link is given here

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/login-page-before-tabs-page-ionic-4/142175/19